# Show that $f(x)={1+\ln x\over x}, x>0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Let $f:(0,+\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be a function with $f(1)=1$ which is differentiable and for which it applies:
>
> $$xf(x)=1-x^2f'(x), \forall x>0$$
>
> Show that $f(x)={1+\ln x\over x}, x>0$

**Personal work:**

$$xf(x)=1-x^2f'(x)\iff_{x\neq0} f(x)={1-x^2f'(x)\over x}$$
We know that $f(1)=1$, so:
$$f(1)=1\iff{1-x^2f'(x)\over x}=1\iff1-x^2f'(x)=x\iff-x^2f'(x)=x-1\iff f'(x)={x-1\over -x^2}$$
That's what I got. What's the problem? The **actual** derivative of $f(x)$ is ${-\ln x\over x^2}$ and not $$\color{red}{x-1\over -x^2}$$

Comment: $f(1)=1$ does not imply $\frac{1-x^2f'(x)}{x}=1$ for all $x$. It would only be true if $x=1$, giving you $1=1-f'(1)$.

Comment: $f(1) = 1 \implies \cfrac{1 - 1^2f'(1)}{1}=1$

Comment: @AlexR. $f'(1)=1$ that's what I got

Comment: isn't it an ODE with boundary conditions?

Comment: @gbox we've not been taught differential equations but they can be used to solve some questions though.

Comment: @AlexanderVoliotis: If you haven't been taught differential equations, then it would suffice to just plug in the proposed solution into the equation and verify the left side equals the right. You will however need ODE theory to prove that the solution is in fact unique.

Comment: Why not involve Picard-Lindelöf? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard–Lindelöf_theorem

Comment: Just curious: do we consider this as a question in calculus or in ode?

Comment: @AlexR. Is there any other way to show that the type of $f$ is ${1+\ln x \over x}$ ?

Comment: @AlexanderVoliotis: Not sure I follow. Either you plug $f$'s solution into the equation and verify it, or you solve the equation using methods from ODEs (see the answers).

Answer (score 2):

Put $y = f(x)$ then $y' +\dfrac{1}{x}y= \dfrac{1}{x^2}\implies xy'+y= \dfrac{1}{x}\implies (xy)' = \dfrac{1}{x}\implies xy = \ln x + C$. Since $x = 1, y = 1\implies C = 1$. Thus $f(x) = \dfrac{\ln x + 1}{x}$ .

Comment: I guess I'm missing something. Where did $y'$ derive from? And at which equation did you let $y=f(x)$

Comment: $y = f(x) \implies f'(x) = \dfrac{df(x)}{dx} = \dfrac{dy}{dx} = y'$.

Answer (score 1):

The homogeneous equation is
$$\frac {f'}{f}=-\frac {1}{x} $$
its solution is

$$f (x)=\frac {\lambda}{x} $$

the variation of the constant gives

$$\lambda'(x)=\frac {1}{x} $$
thus $$\lambda (x)=\ln (x) $$

the general solution is
$$f (x)=\frac {\lambda}{x}+\frac {\ln (x)}{x} =\frac {\lambda+\ln (x)}{x}.$$

$f (1)=1\implies \lambda=1$.

Answer (score 1):

This line is not correct you cant keep f(x) once you asign a value to x
$$f(1)=1\iff{1-x^2f'(x)\over x}=1$$
$$f(1)=1\iff{1-1f'(1)\over 1}=1 \implies f'(1)=0$$

Another hint

$$xf(x)=1-x^2f'(x), \forall x>0$$
$$x^2f'=1-xf$$
$$x^2f'+xf=1$$
$$xf'+f=\frac 1x$$
$$(xf)'=\frac 1x$$
Integrate
$$xf=\int \frac {dx}{x}+K$$
$$f(x)= \frac {\ln|x|+K}x$$
$$f(1)=1 \implies K=1$$
$$\boxed{f(x)= \frac {\ln(x)+ 1}x \quad ; x>0}$$

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is $$x\left(\frac{1+\ln(x)}{x}\right)=1-x^2\left(\frac{-\ln(x)}{x^2}\right)$$

Comment: How did you arrive at that equality?

Comment: I have used your formula, given above.

Comment: $$xf(x)=1-x^2f'(x)$$ where $$f(x)=\frac{1+\ln(x)}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain where you went wrong. You start with 
$$
f(x) = \frac{1-x^2f'(x)}x,\qquad f(1)=1
$$
You then plugged $x=1$ into the left equation, and arrived at 
$$
1 = \frac{1-\color{red}{x}^2f'(\color{red}x)}{\color{red}x}
$$
This is where you made your mistake. When you substitute $x=1$ in an equation, you need to substitute it everywhere. You failed to replace the red $\color{red}x$'s with $1$s.

Going correctly, all you would get would be
$$
1 = \frac{1-1^2f'(1)}{1}\implies f'(1)=0
$$

Comment: I understood my mistake. $f'(1)=0$, now what's next?